# Creating shared library that depends on another shared library using ld

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker, ld

I want to create a shared library `libdependent` that uses certain exported functions from `libparent` using header files.

The path of `libparent` is not known on the build stage, so I can't use `rpath`, and I call `dlopen("path/libparent.so", RLTD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)` and `dlopen("path/libdependent.so", RLTD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)` on run time instead.

But there are no references to `libparent` in `libdependent` file at all if I put `libparent.so` into a library search path during linking and use `-lparent`.

When I try to `dlopen` `libdependent`, I get "cannot locate symbol" error, even though `RTLD_GLOBAL` is set.

What should I do to use exports from `libparent` without calling `dlsym`?

Comment: What linker flags do you use, i.e. what is your link command?

Comment: `-Lpath_to_temp_folder_with_libparent -lparent`.

Comment: I don't know why, but Android `ndk-build` uses `g++` instead of `ld` for linking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you want to create a library, you don't have to import it, so

> dlopen("path/libdependent.so", RLTD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)

is not needed.

Second, if you don't know exactly the name of library (libparent) you will use, you have to use dynamic linking and *dlopen*. In dynamic linking you don't have to inform linker about your libparent library, but you have to use dynamic linker library, so linker command will be like this:

> g++ -o output -dl input.cpp

*dl* says that you will use *dlopen*.

Whe using program, be sure that your libparent.so is visible from running directory (or use absolute path). Also check return value of dlopen to know about success of library opening.

```
    void *handle = NULL;
    handle = dlopen("libparent.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle){
        printf("Error!\r\n");
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't load `libdependent` from itself, I load it from what it is supposed to use. I know the name of `libparent`, but not its path. I tried to add `-dl`, it didn't help. I check the return value and `dlerror`. `libparent` is loaded fine, but when I load `libdependent`, I get "cannot locate symbol somesymbolfromlibparent".

Comment: I compile using Android NDK-Build, the code is just a common header file with the function declared as `extern "C"`, the function body is in `libparent`, the call is in `libdependent`, and there's another library that `dlopen`s both.

Comment: As I understand you have to do 'dlopen' of 'libparent.so' in your libdependent library to properly use functions from 'libparent.so'.
Then do dlopen of libdependent.so in your target program. No need dlopen libparent in it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `-shared` to the linker options and specifying the library in `-l`. `-(` can also be useful.